# $PATH duplication issues

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables, path, oh-my-zsh

If I do `echo $PATH` I get the following:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/kh/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

This is in my ~/.zshrc file:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/opt/X11/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH

I've had to manually add /usr/local/etc... at the front of this file because homebrew was complaining.

I've searched for all possibles files (I know of) to find where $PATH is being built from. But  to no avail. These are

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Was this question ever given an accepted answer or otherwise solved? (It is showing as being 8 years old...)

Answer (score 4):

Default paths are defined in `/etc/paths` on macOS. As a sub-process inherits environment variables and you explicitly set `/usr/bin/` in your `$PATH` you have duplicate entries.

To remove the duplicate entries, you can use:

```
typeset -U PATH
```

The consequence of the above command is that only the *first* instance of any given directory path in the value of `$PATH` will be kept, while later duplicates are removed automatically. The effect is persistent in the current shell session, so adding new duplicates to the variable will be prevented.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which other file is setting your `$PATH` but the duplicated entries are

```
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
```

All of these are set in your `~/.zshrc` so all you need to do is not set them there. In any case, these should all be in the default `$PATH` and there is no need to add them. Most systems come with a default `$PATH` that will include these directories, additions made in users' `~/.zshrc` files should only add non-standard directories.

Change your `$PATH` declaration to

> export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/python:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

According the the [ZSH manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall):

> STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES
>
> Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden.  Subsequent behaviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the former affects all startup files, while the second only affects global startup files (those shown here with an path starting with a /).  If one of the options is unset at any point, any subsequent startup file(s) of the corresponding type will not be read.  It is  also possible for a file in $ZDOTDIR to re-enable GLOBAL_RCS. Both RCS and GLOBAL_RCS are set by default.
>
> Commands  are  then  read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.  Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

Thus, you may want to check:

```
/etc/zshenv
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zlogin
```

and any files they happen to source.  Since you are OS X, it is likely you'll find something like:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

which, according to  [the path_helper man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html), will also look in:

```
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/*
```

Comment: Nothing in:`/etc/zshenv
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zlogin` and can't change order in /etc/paths as some command may rely on using system default version in `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score -1):

You can set additional paths to PATH using the following syntax:

```
PATH=$PATH:/additonally_location
```

So I think that PATH isn't duplicated.

Comment: It is being duplicated though and I want to try and figure out where

Comment: zsh search for a few files in you home, verify if one is duplicating your path: ~/.zshenv, ~/.zprofile, ~/.zlogin

Comment: Thanks. But i've just done that all files are empty or dont exist at all

Comment: @showFocus in that case please update your question to list the zsh files you have searched through, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are irrelevant.