# Why do I have repeating lines in my default $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, centos, path

Using CENTOS 7 and BASH, after creating a new user, the user has repeating lines in the path variable.

I've looked at this site [$PATH duplication issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78807/path-duplication-issues) but it's for a .zshrc. Also, this is for the default profile just after a new user is added, so I'm not doing anything extra.

For example, if I create the user 'bob' and then view bob's path, it looks like this:

```
$ echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
```

As you can see, both `/home/bob/.local/bin` and `/home/bob/bin` are in the path 3 times. The new (default) `.bash_profile` contains the following lines for the path variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Also, anytime I add on a new path to the existing one in `.bash_profile`, the new (added) path also repeats itself. For example, adding `/opt/mystuff` to the path will repeat itself...

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/opt/mystuff
export PATH
```

Will yield...

```
$ echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
/opt/mystuff
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
/opt/mystuff
/home/bob/.local/bin
/home/bob/bin
/opt/mystuff
```

So, why are these path lines repeating themselves and is it a problem?

If it is a problem, how can I fix it?

Thanks for any & all help.

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin` takes the current value of `$PATH`, and sticks `:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin` at its end. And `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/opt/mystuff` takes the now-current value of `$PATH` and sticks `:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/opt/mystuff` at the end... So you get `$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/bin` twice. Perhaps you have a similar assignment somewhere a third time?

Comment: Do you source `~/.bash_profile` repeatedly from e.g. `~/.bashrc`?